# Using Opencv on facebook Photos

Tags: facebook, opencv

i am developing a web application which will retrieve all the albums/photo of a user from facebook google+ and twitter and then apply some image processing on it.how to retrieve the photos and simultaneously use opencv-python on webserver. i am using graph-api to get the list of urls and opencv to process.but what is the best method to do this "is this good to first download the photos and the process and then show the results"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i use urllib.urlretrieve(url_of_photo) to download it and then process it using opencv.